# Make a queue of activities in an activity?

Tags: android

my app requires me to start more than one activity from a single function. i have tried using the following:

```
startActivityForResult()

@Override onActivityResult()
```

result :It would show a splash of each activity.

i wish to make a queue of activities as that the second would run when first finishes and third would run when second finishes.. and so on...
is it possible?
HOW?

Comment: did you tried to return in result the activity number to open the next one as you mentioned ?

Comment: i did returned a response number from the child activity but not sure how to use it to start a new activity.. could you please explain that?

Comment: @Ifrah if my question solved your problem then mark the tick button next to my answer to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign `requestCode` for each activity and then use `startActivityForResult()` to start first activity

```
final int request_code_1=1, request_code_2=2, request_code_3=3 ;
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == 1) // 1=for 1st activity
{
Intent intent = new Intent(first.this, second.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, request_code_2);
}
else if(resultCode == 2) // 2 = 2nd activity
{
Intent intent1 = new Intent(first.this, third.class);
startActivityForResult(intent1,request_code_3);
}
    ..

 and so on
}
```